# Facebook Dev Console - App logo icon not changing, why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-app-settings

Facebook Dev/My Apps

I replaced the "App Icon" in the "App Details" tab but the icon is not changing on the "Dashboard" tab or anywhere else.

Anyone know how to correct this issue?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Did you submit your app details for review before? If so, you need to submit them again after such a change.